# AS2 Receive and Send in C# Azure Function

Tags: azure, biztalk, actionscript-2, ipaas

I'm trying to migrate AS2 BizTalk implementation to Azure iPaaS and I want to avoid the usage of integration account.

I referred below blogs to receive and send AS2 message but not able make much progress.

https://mattfrear.com/2010/07/13/send-as2-with-dotnet/

https://mattfrear.com/2011/01/03/receiving-as2-messages-with-net/

Any help much appreciated.

I added the repo link for Azure Functions
https://github.com/gitdj/AS2IPaasFunc/blob/main/FunctionAppAS2

Here's exception message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2KfT.png)

Here's working solution with Logic App with Integration Account
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj8D6.png)

Comment: What have you tried? What issue are you having?

Comment: I get an exception "asn1 bad tag value met" when decrypting the message.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add both that error message, and a some code that reproduces that error?

Comment: Quick update: I'm able perform as2encoding and as2decoding with Azure Function Apps.  I did few tweaks to mattfrear code (used C# built-In libraries) and understood how BizTalk decodes the as2 message using AS2Decode BizTalk Pipeline component. Currently, AS2Decoder Function is capable of decoding the signed & encrypted messages and constructs the MDN. AS2Encoder does support Signing and Encryption

Comment: I used mimekit in my as2receiver, as it can handle different content transfer encodings. Also mimekit comes in handy to process the mdn thanks to the class MultipartReport. As for the sender, I used MultipartContent to generate the message.

Answer (score 0):

I did what you are describing in your post. ACtually created an azure function for sending and receiving AS2 messages without the use (and costs) of integration account. It is available in Azure Marketplace, named "Integration Microservice for AS2".